# required attribute not working in react js form for validation

Tags: reactjs, required

required is not working. I have tried using required="required" or required={true}.

Can someone explain why or how to easily fix that?

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

export const Login = () => {
const [username, setUsername] = useState("");

const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    console.log("test")
}

return(
                <form className={styles["form-parent"]}>
                    {/* Title */}
                    <h1 className={styles["form-title"]}>Login</h1>

                    {/* Username */}
                    <div className={styles["form-input-group"]}>
                        <label> <b>Username:</b></label>
                        <input className={styles["form-input"]} type="text" name="username"
                            title="Enter your username in this field" required
                            value={username}
                            onChange={(e) => setUsername(e.target.value)}
                        />
                    </div>

                    {/* Login button */}
                    <div className={styles["form-input-group"]}>
                        <input className={styles["form-button"]} type="submit" value="Log In"
                            title="Click here to login"
                            onClick={(e) => handleSubmit(e)}
                        />
                    </div>

                </form>
);
}
```

I have been struggling on this for past 2 days now and internet has not been of much help.

Answer (score 0):

You should set form onSubmit event

add:
`<form onSubmit={(e) => handleSubmit(e)}>`

instead of your button input onClick event

delete:
`onClick={(e) => handleSubmit(e)}`

Comment: btw, it is enough just to use required like you did in your own code

Comment: It still does not work.

Comment: remove ```e.preventDefault();``` from handleSubmit

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this line:

```
onClick={(e) => handleSubmit(e)}
```

Can be as simple as:

```
onSubmit={handleSubmit}
```

Because the event object is passed to the call back function by default.

Here is an example over simplified from posted code, and runs in the below snippets for convenience.

Hopefully this will help by showing the validating status change in real time.

```js
const Login = () => {
  const [username, setUsername] = React.useState("");
  const [message, setMessage] = React.useState("");

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (!username) return;
    //  This can be any action, here it's for display only
    setMessage(`Successfully logged in as ${username}`);
  };

  return (
    //  This will pass event object to function by default
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      {/* Title */}
      <h1>Login</h1>
      {/* Username */}
      <div>
        <label>
          <b>Username:</b>
        </label>
        <input
          type="text"
          name="username"
          title="Enter your username in this field"
          required
          value={username}
          onChange={(e) => setUsername(e.target.value)}
        />
        {/*  This can display a helper text when invalid */}
        <h3 className="helper-text">Please enter a user name</h3>
      </div>
      {/* Login button */}
      <div>
        <input type="submit" value="Log In" title="Click here to login" />
      </div>
      {message && <h3 className="message">{message}</h3>}
    </form>
  );
};

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div className="app">
      <Login />
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector("#root"));
```

```css
input[type="text"]:invalid {
  background-color: ivory;
  border: none;
  outline: 2px solid red;
}

input[type="text"]:invalid + .helper-text {
  color: crimson;
  display: flex;
}

input[type="text"] + .helper-text {
  display: none;
}

input[type="text"] {
  margin-left: 12px;
}

input[type="submit"] {
  margin-top: 12px;
  padding: 6px;
}

.message {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.1.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.1.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```